# Android: scaling SVG in WebView

Tags: android, svg, webview

I have a problem with WebView and SVG. When i load svg (with javascript) into WebView, it scales... randomly. Absolutely randomly on different devices and different screen orientation on one device. I need to place SVG in WebView with fot to WebView size, ventered and enabled zoom. A tried this html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="AutomobileMain.svg" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle">
    <param name="src" value="AutomobileMain.svg" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

It propretly works in browser, but not works in WebView.

Here a code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSchemeImageWebView = (WebView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.newremark_image, container, false);

    WebSettings webSettings = mSchemeImageWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

    mSchemeImageWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new IJavascriptHandler(),
            "android");

    mSchemeImageWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            prepareResizedToFit(mSchemeImageWebView);
        }

    });

    reloadWebView() ;

    return mSchemeImageWebView;
}

public void reloadWebView() {
    mSchemeImageWebView.loadUrl(getSchemePath()) ;
}

private void prepareResizedToFit(WebView webView) {
    webView.setInitialScale(scale(mSchemeImageWebView));
}

private int scale(View view) {
    int height = Math.round(view.getHeight()) ;
    int width = Math.round(view.getWidth()) ;
    Dimension parsedDimension ;
    try {
        parsedDimension = new SVGDimensionsParser().parse(getResources()
                .getAssets().open(getSchemeFileName())) ;
        double scaleXtoMax = width / parsedDimension.width ;
        double scaleYtoMax = height / parsedDimension.height ;
        double scale = Math.min( scaleXtoMax , scaleYtoMax ) ;
        return (int) ( scale * 100.0 ) ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 100;
    }
}

private static class SVGDimensionsParser {
    public Dimension parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,
                    false);
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFeed(parser);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private Dimension readFeed(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getName().equals("svg")) {
            return new Dimension(
                    Double.parseDouble(parser.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "height").replaceAll("px", "")),
                    Double.parseDouble(parser.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "width").replaceAll("px", "")));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be seeing the effects of the device pixel ratio which varies by device.

Try adding the following into the header of your HTML file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If that doesn't work, it might be a problem with how your SVG file is written.  How the SVG is positioned in the window can be affected by various attributes of the root `<svg>` element. Specifically the viewBox, width, height and preserveAspectRatio attributes.

Try tinkering with them. More info on how they work can be found in the SVG spec.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement